# Custom field on CROpportunity doesn't display saved value since upgrading from 6.10 or 2017R2 to 2018R1

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I made a DAC extension on CROpportunity in my customization project which was working well in 6.10 and 2017R2. Now I upgraded my site to 2018R1 and my custom fields don't work anymore. As soon as I save my record, the customized field goes blank even if the database saved the value correctly.

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In version 2018R1, `PX.Objects.CR.CROpportunity` became a projection of `PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.CROpportunity`.

In order for the projection to get its customized fields values correctly, you need to also customize the Standalone DAC and set the BQL Field of `PX.Objects.CR.CROpportunity` point to `PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.CROpportunity`.

Here is an example :

```
public class CROpportunityExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.CROpportunity> 
{
    #region UsrTest
    [PXDBDecimal(BqlField = typeof(CROpportunityStandaloneExt.usrTest))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Test Field")]

    public virtual Decimal? UsrTest { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrTest : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}

public class CROpportunityStandaloneExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.CROpportunity>
{
    #region UsrTest
    [PXDBDecimal]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Test Field")]

    public virtual Decimal? UsrTest { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrTest : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}
```