# Customized fields in Opportunity page are getting cleared after navigating records

Tags: acumatica

I am having the following inconvenient when inserting a 
custom field on a DAC extension, with Acumatica 17.202.0016 and
18.103.0022 version. In both versions I followed the next steps:

1) Created a "Usr" field "UsrCustomString", on the Opportunities page
CR304000, followed by creating its controls and publishing
the customization project.

[Creation of "UsrCustomString" field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukgpw.png)

2) Then I selected an existing Opportunity and assigned a value in the new field.

[Updating record with new value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0I0z.png)

[Checking in DB the updated value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbbGG.png)

After doing this, I noticed that after navigating
to the next record and then selecting back the
OpportunityID "OP000368", the custom field shows blank. The same happens after pressing the cancel button.

[Field is shown blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l5OS.png)

I tried this sequence in the Cases page "CR306000" and it worked
correctly. It seems an issue related to the CROpportunity DAC.

[Definition of the DAC extension with "CustomString" value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smDsM.png)

Comment: It sounds like the fields are not setup as DB fields? The string field should have PXDBString attribute vs PXString attribute. Can you confirm the field is using PXDBString?

Comment: You will find the solution for this issue on this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880116/custom-field-on-cropportunity-doesnt-display-saved-value-since-upgrading-from-6

Comment: Hi Brendan - they are bounded fields. I have updated the question to show the DAC definition. What is unusual is that the first time I save the Opportunity, the data is persisted in the DB. But when I re-access the page, the values are no longer shown.

Comment: Thank you very much @cbetabeta, after doing the solution followed by the link, it worked for me.

Comment: ah yes i forgot the changes for 2018R1 which we spent a good time updating ourselves. I was thinking you were just having this problem in 2017R2 also.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that @cbetabeta, worked well for me. Here is the link for the solution

[Custom field on CROpportunity doesn't display saved value since upgrading from 6.10 or 2017R2 to 2018R1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880116/custom-field-on-cropportunity-doesnt-display-saved-value-since-upgrading-from-6)